# Ionic Native Bar-code Scanner Not Working On Android 8

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, barcode-scanner, ionic-native

I install the barcode scanner plugin for ionic, built my project and it works on the ff android os: Android 51.1, Android 6 and Android 7, but it fails on android 8. Once I try to use the barcode scanner the application crashes. What could be the issue?

This is my ionic info:

**Ionic:**

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.9.0 (C:\Users\Juls\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
```

**Cordova:**

```
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, (and 8 other plugins)
```

**System:**

```
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Juls\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.14.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove android platform

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

2) Add latest version of android(which support android sdk 28(android 8))

```
ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0
```

Ref. : https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/16/cordova-android-release-8.0.0.html

Comment: still cant run on android 8.1.0, havent tried on android 8.0.0 yet but should it support 8.1.0 as well ?

Answer (score 1):

May be the **barcode scanner plugin** is not supported for the latest android version so try removing the plugin and add the latest version of barcode scanner

Refer the ionic documentation [plugin here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/)

Comment: Thank you @Sivaramakrishnan, updated the plugin but unfortunately their plugin doesnt support android 8. SO bad

Comment: oh..check if there is any other way